How many Hikari connection are created by default in spring boot
I have a springboot application with v2.7.5 and v3.0.0 . Its has 2 Oracle DB properties and I have defined 3 datasources. But When I run the springboot v3 application I can see in logs  that 3 Hikari configurations are created while in springboot v2.7.5 only 2 hikari configurations are created. Any idea of this behaviour.
